# How to get the auto-generated ID from .set() in firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const docRef = await db.collection('Safes').add(data[i])
```

When I am using .add(data), I get the auto generated ID for that document in **docRef.id**.
But when I change the .add() to .set() to avoid duplicates in my collection, printing the docRef.id gives the output as "undefined".

```
const docRef = await db.collection('Safes').doc().set(data[i])
```

How can I get the ID while using .set()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set()` won't give you the ID.  The ID is available in the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) returned by [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc).  You will want to rewrite your code more like this:

```
const docRef = await db.collection('Safes').doc()
const id = docRef.id
await docRef.set(data[i])
```